# Can't see the pod logs on google GKE

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a deployment on google gke, and I can't see the pod logs on the console even though the Cloud logging is enabled on the cluster?
So what could be the issue? did I miss something?

Comment: Welcome to SOF! Please give more information, like the error you receive, what you typed,... See how to ask a good question here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: No errors, just when I check the deployment in the overview to see the CPU, MEM, DISK all it says is: no data is available for the selected time frame.

Comment: Have you tried `kubectl logs deploy/<deployment>` and `kubectl describe deploy/<deployment>` to see what it returns?

Comment: Did you enable application logs in the GKE cluster logging section?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like Workload monitoring and logging may not have been enabled and currently it's only doing system monitoring and logging. Please see the docs here on how to change the logging settings: https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/docs/solutions/gke/installing#installing

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I found the reason,I found out that the cluster was using a specific service account that hasn't logging and monitoring roles assigned. I assigned those roles to that service account and everything is working well.